# Localizing Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, localization

HOw to localize classic asp?

I got something from below link

http://networkprogramming.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!D79966C0BAAE2C7D!379.entry

but when i do that, i am getting error.

Error Type:
Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01A8)
Object required: 'xmlResx'
/MySite/default.asp, line 14

Comment: Please post the code here instead of providing a link, which requires signing into other website.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you code has access to the Msxml.dll file that is used when calling this line

`Set xmlResx=Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")`

Comment: Thanks to all,Somehow i managed to do this.
Function Translate(english)
 Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
 objXML.async = False
 objXML.Load (Server.MapPath("LocalizeStrings.xml"))
 Set objLst = objXML.getElementsByTagName("data")
 For i = 0 to (objLst.length -1)
  EnglishText = objLst.item(i).attributes.getNamedItem("name").text
  If english=EnglishText Then
   Translate= objLst.item(i).text
   Exit For
  End If
 Next
End Function

Answer (score 1):

It appears you don't have the dll installed XMLDOM, thats why it says object required. Did you register the dll on the server? Are you sure there is XMLDOM available?    You were considering to upgrade to .net? If you are going to switch languages switch to PHP... trust me i was a long time Classic ASP guru, and I didn't like php at first, but its a dream come true... everything is free most host include everything... with asp you have to buy a 100+ $ program just to thumbnail images!  And xml is built in also...

Comment: Thanks jason,
This is not migration, this is to localize an existing application.